# Motivation for triple cover of $A_6$ (and $A_7$)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

In finite simple groups by Wilson, he constructs the triple cover of $A_6$ by considering the action of the subgroup of $A_6$ preserving the partition $\{12, 34, 56\}$ on the two vectors $(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)$ and $(0, 1, 0, 1, \omega, \omega^*)$ where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity

He then adjoins further elements permuting the set of vectors generated, and shows that the resulting group is a triple cover of $A_6$

What is the motivation for this, and why is it exceptional?

I can somewhat see how to motivate it as we want to basically make “copies” of $A_6$ (corresponding to each cubic root of unity) lie over $A_6$, but this doesn’t explain to me

(A) why there aren’t higher covers of $A_6$

(B) why there aren’t higher covers than double of $A_n$ for $n > 7$

Similarly (for basically the same reasons) the triple cover of $A_7$ by extending the set of vectors by $(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$ and considering the symmetries of the $7$ orthogonal sets of $6$ vectors doesn’t really seem motivated to me

Comment: There are some other constructions here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentiner_group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentiner_group). The covering groups are classified by the Schur multiplier [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_multiplier), see also here [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_groups_of_the_alternating_and_symmetric_groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_groups_of_the_alternating_and_symmetric_groups)

Comment: I am tempted just to answer that these statements are true because they have been proved to be true. Why are they surprising? It happens very often in mathematics that general properties of infinite classes of objects have a few small exceptions. I guess you could ask why are the Schur multipliers (and also the outer automorphism groups) of the finite simple groups moderately small, but I am sceptical whether this has any sensible answer.

Comment: @DerekHolt
I'm not really asking why it's true.

At some point, a person must have come up with this construction for the triple cover.

I'm asking what could have motivated that person to think of this way of constructing it

Comment: and then the further question of "why doesn't my intuition for why you'd think of this work to generalise it to higher $A_n$?"